# Selectable Text in VBA Message Box

Tags: vba, user-interface, excel

When I create a msgbox in VBA, the user cannot interact with the text at all. In my case, I want the user to be able to highlight and copy the text. I'm thinking the better way to do this may be to add a button that copies the text to the clipboard. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered to make a custom message box form?

Comment: If I was more experienced in VBA and knew how to, that sounds like the path I'd go down. However, my experience is small and, as it is, my time is quite limited.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For this code:

```
msgbox "Does Control+C work on a lowly, old message box?"
```

you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, open notepad, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and you will get this:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Excel
---------------------------
Does Control+C work on a lowly, old message box?
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Yes, but not user friendly :)

Answer (score 14):

If you want text that is "selectable" then don't use MsgBox. [Use a Custom form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/controls-dialogboxes-forms/create-a-custom-dialog-box) and instead of a label use a textbox. However...

Change these properties of the textbox in design mode.

1. SpecialEffect - fmiSpecialEffectFlat
2. BackStyle - Transparent
3. Locked - True

And then use this code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Caption = "Message Box"
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Any ideas on how to deal with multi-line messages? `WordWrap = True` doesn't seem to make the text actually wrap.

Comment: Right... Um, I was just checking whether *you* knew ;-)

Comment: `Multiline = True`

Answer (score 13):

You can use an inputbox instead of a message box

```
inputbox "Copy the below text", "Copy Text", "Text value"
```

inputbox copy text

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use VBA to set the clipboard text if the user typically would copy the entire message.

Or use input box instead of msgbox, since the user can copy from the populated value.

Answer (score 4):

You could make your own custom message box using a UserForm. Here's a rudimentary proof-of-concept: a userform with one text box (from which you can select and copy text).

[image]

```
Sub MyMsg(msg As String)
    With MsgUserForm ' this is the name I gave to the userform
        .TextBox1.Text = msg
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
MyMsg "General failure reading hard drive."
```