# Populate Excel MsgBox with last row cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to yield a message box that a user can copy text from. This message box should contain two last row cell values as follows:

```
     -MsgBox-
'First Value: xxxx'
'Second Value: xxxx'
```

I have the following vba to find the last cell number:

```
Dim Lastrow As String
Lastrow = sumsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

I am wanting to output the last cell S and T values to a message box that a user can copy text from. The below is not correct, although it gives you an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
MsgBox.Range(("S" & Lastrow), ("T" & Lastrow))
```

EDIT: I should mention that my last 'T' cell contains a formula. I am trying to populate the box with the value the formula yields.

EDIT2: This is different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188769/selectable-text-in-vba-message-box) as I want the user to be able to actually select the text from the box itself. Also I couldn't decipher how to actually create the input box in my context (sorry, I am a beginner).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selectable Text in VBA Message Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188769/selectable-text-in-vba-message-box)

Comment: You should show evidence about your input and output by adding some picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow:

```
Dim Lastrow As String
Lastrow = sumsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Call MsgBox("First Value: " & sumsht.Range("S" & Lastrow) & vbNewLine & "Second Value: " & sumsht.Range("T" & Lastrow))
```

Comment: your solution works but still doesn't allow the user to highlight and copy the text.

Also the 'T' cell value is not populating into the MsgBox, I believe this may be due to the fact that the 'T' cell contains a formula. I want to return the value that the formula yields in the MsgBox.

Comment: I did, and edited my question. Thanks for your help!